# Repeat tasks - mark done in a datetree

Tags: org-mode

In my org file, I have the following lines:

```
#+STARTUP: logdone logrepeat logreschedule logredeadline logrefile logdrawer
#+ARCHIVE: ::datetree/
```

When I mark a repeat task done, I want to:

1. Continue doing everything that is happening now (the task gets a new scheduled date, an entry is added in the :LOGBOOK: drawer, etc.) **and additionally,**
2. Make an entry in the datetree with DONE as the state for the task

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
(require 'org-datetree)
(defun my/log-to-datetree ()
  "Log the done item to the datetree."
  (when (equal org-state "DONE")
    (org-datetree-file-entry-under
     (format "* DONE %s" (nth 4 (org-heading-components)))
     (calendar-current-date))))

(add-hook 'org-after-todo-state-change-hook #'my/log-to-datetree t)
```

Comment: No. It does nothing for me.

Comment: Turns out a nil snuck into the call to add-hook. I edited the code above to fix it, and also made sure that org-datetree is loaded. Seems to work with both Org 8 and Org 9 on my system.